# Why do I get the segmentation fault message at run time? (2-dimensional array of struct)

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc

So basically I'm trying to use malloc to create a 2-dimensional array of structs. But, as stated in the title, I fail.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;

typedef struct boxes
{
    bool ving;
    bool ved;
    int data;
} boxes;

void init_boxes(int sz, boxes **box);

int main(void)
{
    int N, i, j;
    boxes **box;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    init_boxes(N, box);

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d", &box[i][j].data);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", box[i][j].data);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void init_boxes(int sz, boxes **box)
{
    int i;

    box = (boxes **) malloc(sz * sizeof(boxes));
    for(i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        box[i] = (boxes *) malloc(sz * sizeof(boxes));
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I comment out the part where I set the data to something I input there is no problem, but I can't find any problem with the two fors.

Comment: I can compile this program with no issues.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I meant at run-time...

Comment: If you consistently get a segmentation fault *compiling* your program then your compiler is broken.  Period.

Comment: If your program fails with a segmentation fault at run time, then it almost certainly means it is trying to access memory that does not belong to it.  Consider running it under a tool such as `valgrind` to better determine the nature of the problem, or running it under a debugger to pinpoint the location where the failure occurs.

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` (e.g. returned by `malloc()`) to/from other pointers!

Comment: C is pass by value. This question is a duplicate out of "many".

Comment: Also the code shown misses error checking for the call to `malloc()`. The latter migth very well return `NULL`.